# Problem with nhibernate join

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to do a join like this using fluent nhibernate:

```
Id(x => x.Id);
Map(x => x.SourceSystemRecordId,"sourceSystemRecord_id");
```

Then

```
Join("cat.tbl_SourceSystemRecords", SourceSystemRecords);
```

But, it seems I don't have a way to specify the column I want to join with from the first table, in this case I need to join on SourceSystemRecordId and not on Id

Is there any way I can specify this? I tried References() but that requires me to create an object for this relationship, what I need is to aggregate the columns in sourcesystem records to the ones in the main table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried References() but that requires
>   me to create an object for this
>   relationship

Did you tried Expand method for references?

EDIT: Expand method joining columns which is referenced. and if you dont want to use lazy loading, this is how can you fix.

ps. still i cant understand it clearly. If this is not what you want, please give more details / examples.

eg.

Database:

```
Examples:
-Id

SourceSystemRecords:
-Id
-ExampleId
```

Entity:

```
Example:
Id / int
SourceSystemRecords / SourceSystemRecords - Referenced
```

Query:

```
Session.Linq<Example>().Expand("SourceSystemRecords")
```

Comment: What do you mean expand, I'm using nhibernate, can you clarify a little bit more please?

Comment: I edited. -or- I should ask, I think you just want get referenced properties in one query - not lazy loading. Am i right?